# Изменить курсор мыши, или прикрепить к ней гифку, во время ajax команды

Tags: ajax, javascript

Доброго всем вечера, ночи

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if(id != '1' && id != '15'){
            dlinna = id.length;
            if(dlinna < '20'){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "adjagz.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {id: id},
                    success: function(text) {
                        $("#text").html(text);
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                $.ajax({
                    url: "adjagz.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {id: id},
                    success: function(text) {
                        $("#tsst").html(text);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
</script><!--ajax-->
```

Собственно **скопилефтил** с хэшкода. Нажимаем нужную ссылку, идет POST запрос к adjagz.php. Как только все сделано, обновляется <div id=\"text\"></div> интересует только - #text.

Можно ли как то изменить курсор мышки, что бы было видно что "комп думает"? или гифку какую ни будь рядом с курсором сделать (это чаще видел в инете)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

стиль

```
.some
{
    cursor:wait;
}
```

через js подтягиваете на body этот класс, и все..

Comment: ох, класс то я прописать смогу, знать бы как остальное сделать. я так понял нужно какие то команды до success и после прописать?

Answer (score 2):

```
$("a").click(function() {
    ....
    if(id != '1' && id != '15'){
        $('body').addClass('some');
        ....
            success:function(text) {
                $('body').removeClass('some');
                ....    
            }
        ....
});
```