# Изменить класс курсора, во время выполнения js скрипта

Tags: javascript

Доброго дня.

При передаче id ajax скрипту, система начинает думать. Подскажите, как поменять стиль курсора, во время выполнения скрипта?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {id: id},
// сдесь начинает думать 5-10секунд
    success: function(text) {
        $("#text").html(text);
    }
// сдесь заканчивает думать
});

//css
.some{cursor:wait;}
```

p.s. [здесь узнал что хотя бы через классы это делается](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/163527/javascript-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-ajax-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

добавить до ajax:

```
$('body').addClass('some');
```

Добавить в success:

```
$('body').removeClass('some');
```

Comment: @lampa спасибо огромное! Думал будет темный лес, а оказалось просто все